# Assertion to check signal transition at the posedge of clock

Tags: system-verilog-assertions

I want to do an assertion which checks for the transition of a signal only on the positive edge of the clock. If the signal changes other than the positive edge it should produce an error.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

A1: assert property (@(clock) clock == 1'b1 |=> signal == $past(signal));